# d3js: Draw line - attach one end to g and one end to svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I simply want to draw a line which is attached to `g` with `x1/y1` and to `svg` with the other end `x2/y2`.

The reason is because I have a `div` at the right side of my map and the line should point to it. Now when scrolling around in the map, the one end should always point to the `div` at the right side and the other end should point i.e. on california.

I've created a JSFiddle where you can change `g` to `svg` to see what I mean.
How can I use both?

```js
g.append('line')
 .style("stroke", "lightgreen")
 .style("stroke-width", 10)
 .attr("x1", 960)
 .attr("y1", 200)
 .attr("x2", 200)
 .attr("y2", 400);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmn81xk3/9/

Comment: Why is this tagged with HTML?

Comment: i removed the tag

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by connecting.  `line` is an svg element. It would have to be within one of those two group elements. (assuming you're referring to your 'g' and  `svg` variable)

Comment: you cannot have a line on both g and svg (simultaneously inside and outside the g container). It'll be the same as you being in two different places. And by the way, your svg const is actually a g inside the svg element. What you can do is, add a line to another g, independent of the zoom and, everytime you apply a transformation with zoom, you recalculate x1/y1